# What are the secure and insecure css styles (what would we filter out and what would we allow)?

Tags: css, regex, security, xss, sanitization

I want to allow custom css submitted by users on my website.

I know that some combinations of the styles may not be safe, for example a `position:absolute`.

And yet, the above would not hurt if we wrap that content in a div with `position:relative`.

I also heard there are some possibilities to execute a script through a css, but I couldn't recall or think of any.

So there goes my question:

- Which ones may be considered safe?
- And what would go into a black list?

Ideally I am going to write I function that will accept the content of style="*" tags, and sanitize them accordingly.

I would also consider some advice, on what approach would be better:

- matching and filtering out the unsafe attributes from a black list,
- or allowing to bypass only the ones contained in the white list (though the list might get huge)

If you've got some extensive funcs in your artillery - this is the right place to spit it out! :-)

Comment: IE's non-standard `behavior` and `expression` properties would be first on the list. I'd definitely consider a whitelist over a blacklist, though. That said, I don't know if even a whitelist would cover all cases.

Comment: I never heard that `position:absolute` could be unsafe. I understand `behavior`, `expression` and properties that accept an URL may be unsafe, but `position`?

Comment: @Boltclok Yeap, Ideally though, we just wouldn't need to allow all of them, ther e are some that are deprecated, some are just uncommon and useless, the other ones require css3 which we could safely exclude. I might be wrong but I would guess having about ~30ish in white list would suffice for most of the situations.

Comment: @bfavaretto you are right perhaps it's not a best example. Yet I've seen quite a number of people complaining about it.

Comment: It might be "unsafe" in the sense that it can break your layout if you don't know what you're doing...

Comment: are you sure that 'unsafe' means only  break your own layout? i don't know much about css security but i can imagine that e.g. on facebook user creates his own css, then other user comes to see the page and... his browser stops responding, sends requests for stylesheets with cookies, run injected js etc. is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what you mean by security. If you mean "don't let the user break my layout", then I don't think you can let the user use much in the way of CSS at all. Perhaps font, colors, and backgrounds would be okay to let the user change, but beyond that you're asking for trouble. (even things like margin and padding can be "fun" with negative values in any field, particularly when combined with zindex...) As a general rule of thumb, if there were HTML tags for it (e.g. `<font>`, `<i>`, etc.) then it's going to be okay here.

Now if you are talking about security in that you want to prevent cross site scripting problems, then you need to disallow any css items which can potentially execute code. (e.g. as BoltClock's comment indicates)

If I were you though I would follow the advice of the commenters and simply not let people use CSS -- if there are a couple of customizations you want users to be able to make to the code then let them make those customizations; but don't let them enter arbitrary code. People break these kinds of filters all the time and it's unlikely that you'd catch every possible corner case.